# Need a help : Jmeter POST parameter with request email address - (@ symbol treated as %40) and also invalid password is supporting

Tags: jmeter, symbols

Steps ;
Step 1:
I was adding 32 login users through csv

Step2:
I have added information under below screen shots

Step3:
After importing under the listener tree

Output: (@ symbol treated as %40) and also invalid password is supporting

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related Csv file sample

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely expected, [HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request sends its parameters via browser's query string as a part of an URL and URL does only support a limited subset of alphanumeric characters plus `; , / ? : @ & = + $ - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) #`

Others like `@` need to be [URL-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) and this is exactly what JMeter is doing.

I don't think your test configuration is correct, for example sensitive data like credentials isn't supposed to be passed via GET method as it can easily get sniffed/intercepted, most probably you need to change the request method to [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST).

Also be aware that you can always just record your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) so you won't have to guess the request structure and avoid mistakes like this one.

Comment: Hello Dmitri, Still i'm facing the same. Even though i have used the post method. Still i'm getting the 40%.